# Convergence in measure in finite measure space

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and $f: X \to \mathbb R$ and $f_n: X \to \mathbb R$ measurable for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Why does then $f_n$ converge to $f$ in measure if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|} d \mu = 0?$$

Comment: First start by showing that $\rho(f,g) = \int_X \frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}\ \mathsf d\mu$ is a metric on the (equivalence classes) of functions in $L^1(X,\mathcal A, \mu)$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{x}{1+x}$ is increasing an non-negative on $x\geq0$. If $A_{n,\epsilon}$ is the set where $|f(x)-f_n(x)|\geq\epsilon$, then its measure is finite. Then $\int\frac{|f-f_n}{1+|f-f_n|}=\int_{A_{n,\epsilon}}+\int_{A_{n,\epsilon}^c}\geq m(A_{n,\epsilon})\epsilon + \int_{A_{n,\epsilon}}\frac{|f-f_n|}{1+|f-f_n|}\geq m(A_{n,\epsilon})\epsilon\geq0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick method is to realize that, in a finite measure space, convergence in measure is equivalent to that, for every subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ of $(f_{n})$, there is a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_{l}}})$ of $(f_{n_{k}})$ such that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow f$ a.e.

Now take an arbitrary subsequence $(f_{n_{k}})$ of $(f_{n})$, and we have $$\int\dfrac{|f_{n_{k}}-f|}{1+|f_{n_{k}}-f|}d\mu\rightarrow 0.$$ Convergence in $L^{1}$ implies some a.e. convergent subsequence, so $$\frac{|f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|}{1+|f_{n_{k_{l}}}-f|}\rightarrow 0 \quad\text{a.e.}$$ for some subsequence $(f_{n_{k_{l}}})$ of $(f_{n_{k}})$, now it follows that $f_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow f$ a.e.